# Не получается вывести гиф-файл в отдельный поток

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Не получается запустить гифку во время подключения камеры `cv2`.

Попытался реализовать многопоточность, но ничего не вышло, требуется помощь.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
import cv2


class Worker(QRunnable):
    def  __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()   
    def run(self):
        self.load = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.load.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.load.resize(100, 100)     
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.load.setCentralWidget(label)
        self.movie = QMovie("gif.gif",QtCore.QByteArray())
        self.movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
        label.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()
        self.load.show()
        
    def stop(self):
        self.load.hide()
        self.movie.stop()



class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
                QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
                
                self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
                self.worker = Worker()
                self.threadpool.start(self.worker)
                
                self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
                self.cam.set(3, 640)
                self.cam.set(4, 480)
                
                self.woker.stop()
                self.show()

                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Виджеты не являются потокобезопасными.
Вы никогда не должны изменять или создавать виджеты из других потоков,
кроме основного потока.

Вы не показали ваше подключение камеры,
поэтому я добавил фрагмент своего кода.

Установите свою гифку и другие вещи и попробуйте:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import cv2
import time
import imutils                                   # pip install imutils
import numpy as np


faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
    'opencv_videos/Face_Frame_Rate_plot/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml' # Установите свой путь !
)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("lena-2.png")) 
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        
        self.tmp = None               # Будет удерживать временное изображение для отображения
        self.brightness_value_now = 0 # Обновлено значение яркости
        self.blur_value_now = 0       # Обновлено значение размытия
        self.fps = 0

        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.loadImage)    

#        self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#        self.cam.set(3, 640)
#        self.cam.set(4, 480)

    def loadImage(self):
        """ Эта функция загрузит камеру, получит изображение 
        и установит для него метку с помощью функции setPhoto.
        """
#        cam = False                                           # True  для видеофайла   !!!  
        cam = True                                           # True  для веб-камеры   !!!
        if cam:
            vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        else:
            vid = cv2.VideoCapture('Samonastrojka.avi')  # укажите здесь путь к вашему видеофайлу !!!

        cnt = 0
        frames_to_count = 20
        st = 0
        fps = 0
        
        while(vid.isOpened()):
            img, self.image = vid.read()
            self.image  = imutils.resize(self.image ,height = 480 )
            
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
            faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
                gray,
                scaleFactor=1.15,  
                minNeighbors=7, 
                minSize=(80, 80), 
                flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
            
            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                cv2.rectangle(self.image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (10, 228,220), 5) 
            
            if cnt == frames_to_count:
                try:         
                    print(frames_to_count/(time.time()-st),'FPS') 
                    self.fps = round(frames_to_count / (time.time()-st)) 
                    st = time.time()
                    cnt = 0
                except:
                    pass

            cnt += 1
            self.update()
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if key == ord("q"):
                break
    
    def setPhoto(self, image):
        """ Эта функция принимает ввод изображения и изменяет его размер 
        только для отображения и преобразует его в QImage для установки на метке.
        """
        self.tmp = image
        image = imutils.resize(image,width=640)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0],frame.strides[0],QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def update(self):
        img = self.changeBrightness(self.image, self.brightness_value_now)
        img = self.changeBlur(img, self.blur_value_now)
        self.setPhoto(img)    

    def changeBrightness(self, img, value):
        """ Эта функция будет принимать изображение (img) и значение яркости. 
        Он выполнит изменение яркости с помощью OpenCv 
        и после разделения объединит img и вернет его.
        """
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)
        lim = 255 - value
        v[v>lim] = 255
        v[v<=lim] += value
        final_hsv = cv2.merge((h,s,v))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(final_hsv,cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
        return img
        
    def changeBlur(self, img, value):
        """ Эта функция принимает в качестве входных данных изображение img 
        и значения размытия. После выполнения операции размытия с использованием 
        функции opencv он возвращает изображение img.
        """
        kernel_size = (value+1, value+1)     
        img = cv2.blur(img, kernel_size)
        return img


class GifSplashScreen(QSplashScreen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GifSplashScreen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.movie = QMovie('Data/splash.gif')                    # Установите свой путь к .gif 

        self.movie.frameChanged.connect(self.onFrameChanged)
        self.movie.start()

    def onFrameChanged(self, _):
        self.setPixmap(self.movie.currentPixmap())

    def finish(self, widget):
        self.movie.stop()
        super(GifSplashScreen, self).finish(widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    splash = GifSplashScreen()
    splash.show()

    def createWindow():
        app.w = MyWindow() 
        
        # Имитация начального отображения 
        splash.showMessage('Ожидание отображения интерфейса', Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom, Qt.white)
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: (
                splash.showMessage('Загрузка завершена', 
                    Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom, Qt.white), 
                app.w.show(),
                splash.finish(app.w)
            )
        )
        
    splash.showMessage('Ожидание создания интерфейса', Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom, Qt.white)
    QTimer.singleShot(3000, createWindow)  

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]